# Drupal CKeditor Custom Styles dropdown

Tags: drupal, module, ckeditor, styles

I'm using Drupal 7.43 and the ckeditor version 4. I want to change custom styles dropdown, so I copied the ckeditor.styles.js file into my theme root directory. In configuration (drupal module) I select to use this file from theme directory but the dropdown is empty. And custom path to this file doesn't work too. Here my changes in ckeditor.styles.js file. With the default markdown the dropdown still's empty. Are there any configuration steps that I missed?

```
if(typeof(CKEDITOR) !== 'undefined') {
CKEDITOR.addStylesSet( 'drupal',
[
         /* Block Styles */

        { name : 'interner Link'        , element : 'a', styles : { 'color' : '#004684' } },
        { name : 'externer Link'        , element : 'a', styles : { 'color' : '#004684' } },
        { name : 'E-Mail'       , element : 'a', styles : { 'color' : '#004684' } },
        { name : 'Download'     , element : 'a', styles : { 'color' : '#004684' } },

        /* Inline Styles */

        /* Object Styles */

        {
                name : 'left Image',
                element : 'img',
                attributes :
                {
                        'style' : 'padding: 5px; margin-right: 5px',
                        'border' : '2',
                        'align' : 'left'
                }
        },

        {
                name : 'right Image',
                element : 'img',
                attributes :
                {
                        'style' : 'padding: 5px; margin-left: 5px',
                        'border' : '2',
                        'align' : 'right'
                }
        }
]);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

realpenx, I was also banging my head against this.

In your custom styles.js file, the styleset needs to be named 'drupal' for ckeditor to pick it up, even if you use config.styleSet = "your_custom_styleset".

For those who may run into a similar issue, I'll elaborate. My setup was as follows: Ckeditor was set to load ckeditor.config.js from theme path. Within that file, I had the following:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) { config.styleSet = "my_custom_styleset"; }
```

I defined the path to my ckeditor.styles.js path in the CKEDITOR module settings, and within that file I had:

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'my_custom_styleset', [ 
  // some styles 
]);
```

My styles dropdown was empty and greyed out. I had to change 'my_custom_styleset' to 'drupal' for it to populate.  Weird. I'm probably doing something wrong somewhere, but it wasn't obvious if I was.

Comment: Thank you - I need to mark your answer as solution, because in my blank drupal installation it works now. But in my current project it doesn't. I disabled my modules step by step but I can't figure out whats wrong. I will what over it when I start my next project and when I found out what was wrong, I will complement it. Hope drupal 8 will provide better editor-solutions - it's very bad in 7.

Comment: I can report I saw the same problem in one of my installations - what I could identify so far was that i must be the theme that I use there. Switched to one of the drupal core themes, and it perfectly picked up the ckeditor.styles.js file with its configuration from there ...

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if I would mark the answer above as correct since it is misleading for this issue at hand. In your original post you clearly show that your StyleSet is called 'drupal' - so that was not the issue in your case. I very much also guess it was a theme conflict.

Answer (score 0):

In `admin/config/content/ckeditor` go into the profile you want to edit. Under CSS, you should find a dropdown called "Predefined styles". Under this dropdown, you should find an option that says "Define path to ckeditor.styles.js" and then you can put the path to the file in the text box below it.

[image: Screenshot of the CKEditor configuration page]

Note: I am not sure if this is what you meant by

> "In configuration (drupal module) I select to use this file from theme directory but the dropdown is empty. And custom path to this file doesn't work too."

I interpreted it as going to `admin/config/content/ckeditor/editg`. If this is not the case, let me know and I will change my answer to something more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your solution also before my post. It seems that the file is found but the markup is wrong - but I'm not sure. I changed the basic file in editor directory and the dropdown is empty too. So I think that this is not a path-problem. I think that I exhausted the basic configuration possibilities of ckeditor. Maybe it's a problem of the jquery versions. But there are't any errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the issue for the site where the styles were not working. It wasn't a drupal cache issue, not a theme issue, but a browser cache issue.
As a background, I may have set the *Predefined styles* to "Use theme ckeditor.styles.js" before I actually had the correct ckeditor.styles.js file in the themes directory when I tested the setting, which could have messed up my cached files too - as it failed to load the editor correctly then.
I've tried many ideas that I came across, clearing drupal cache, jquery update version, ... Switching back to a drupal core theme suddenly worked, which made me wonder about my theme. After testing the site in a clean browser (you can also try incognoto or private mode) the styles show up ... maybe this answer/report saves someone else some time ...